# PHP mysqli_fetch_array stopping at 360 results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a conundrum I'm struggling to crack.

I have a database with **719** entries that I'm running a script on, these entries are Characters in a game and is what they will be referenced as.

However my `while` loop stops at **360** every time...

See below:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY entryID;");
// Start loopy loop
$runCount = 0;
$CharNum = 0;
echo "NumRows = ".mysqli_num_rows($query)."<br/>"; // Outputs: NumRows = 719

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "Character#: ".++$CharNum."<br/>"; // Outputs: Counter stops at 360??
    $entryID = $row["entryID"];
    $CharacterID = $row["characterID"];
    $blue = $row["blue"];
    $tsDatabaseID = $row["tsDatabaseID"];
    $tsUniqueID = $row["tsUniqueID"];
    $tsName = $row["tsName"];

    if (...[tonnes of code here]
    }
    echo "Runcount = ".++$runCount."<br/>"; // Outputs: Another counter stops at 360??
}
echo [some report summary]
```

I have no idea how or why it is stopping, but it isn't crashing as the report summary is showing after the `while` finishes but it is too perfect to be 360 every time??

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Check the [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). Is that correct?

Comment: Just to make sure... you have nothing touching `$query` inside that `[tonnes of code here]` do you?

Comment: Suspicious: 360 is exactly half of 719 (rounded). Check for double increment.

Comment: IncredibleHat I've just checked with Ctrl+F and definitely not.
@tadman num_rows is correct, I've checked it in the database. I will take a look at Object though, Procedure is just habit.

Comment: Well then this is baffling. Have you streamlined your test by just doing the while on results with nothing else BUT a ++$counter?

Comment: This might be information overload, but: http://www.sev3rance.com/ts3apitest/cron.php
++$variable only increments once doesn't it? It is certainly counting up in 1's on the job.
@IncredibleHat Do you mean comment out the if?

Comment: ++$var in an expression just means it returns the new value after increment (instead of the value before increment). It shouldn't be incrementing by half though... thats a scary thought though if it is :)

Comment: Yes, comment out that whole if and tonnes of code. Just so it does the basics of that while loop.

Comment: Check if the printed out record details correspond to the first 360 records you expect. If you see that your code skips every 2nd record, then you may double fetch your data.

Comment: Commenting out the `if` counts correctly up to 719, so thank you. It looks like potentially I have a stray `continue`where there shouldn't be one.

Comment: Is `[tonnes of code here]` too much code to post here? Hehe...

Comment: 250 lines lol however why would even a `continue` mess up the counter that is before the `if`?? :S

Comment: is the last `$entryID = $row["entryID"];` the actual last entry in database?

Comment: @Shadow is correct, looking at the database, it is skipping every other record.

Comment: Order should be: "Wayne Kherr" then "Renosha Argaron" then "FuriousPig" then "Snakester". However it is just going Wayne, then FuriousPig.

Comment: So fun story,
    `if (!mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {`
Doesn't sanity check it like I thought, but performs the fetch in a way it screws everything up. Perhaps someone can explain this who is better than I.

Answer (score 0):

So fun story,

`if (!mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {`

Doesn't sanity check it like I thought to see if it's valid, but performs the fetch in a way it screws everything up. Perhaps someone can explain this who is better than I. But this was inside my `if`.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` is going to fetch another row. It doesn't not fetch it just because it's in an if condition.